# Reverse GeoLocation

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

Is my gps location my exact location? If so can anyone provide some resources to convert latitude longitude position into a city or a place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my gps location my exact location?

This can vary depending on where you are actually situated. Usually GPS signals tend to have a margin of error between 5 and 50m. This can be reduced with the help of cell towers and other network structures. Having a clear, unobstructed view of the sky also helps in getting an accurate signal.

> If so can anyone provide some resources to convert latitude longitude
>   position into a city or a place.

You can try using Google's [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) or else [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) which is an open source counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
Geocoder gCoder = new Geocoder(myContext);
ArrayList<Address> addresses = gCoder.getFromLocation(123456789, 123456789, 1);
if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
Toast.makeToast(myContext, "country: " + adresses.get(0).getCountryName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: i have no problem with same code. i use context of activity in palce of MyContext as Myactivity.this and its working